# Loading data from a file and inserting into the array depending on the length of the first line

Tags: java

The first line in the file has years and the number of these years indicates the size of the table. For example, I have the years 2015 2016 2017 then the table will store three numbers. Values for variables can be from 1 to number of years.
If there are fewer than the number of years, the remaining ones are determined on the last of the given values.
My problem is that I do not know how to add these numbers to the table.

File for example.

YEARS   2015 2016 2017 2018 2019

IMP 1.03 1.04 1.07

```
public class Main{
 private int years;
 private double [] IMP;
 private StringTokenizer st;
 private String text;

 public void readFromFile(String fname){

 try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname))){
  text = br.readLine();
  st = new StringTokenizer(text);
  years = st.countTokens() - 1;

  IMP = new double[years];
  text = br.readLine();
  String split [] = text.split("[ \t]");

  int i =0;
  while(i<years){
   IMP[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]); // here is my problem. I dont know how set data here
  }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Output should be

YEARS   2015 2016 2017 2018 2019

IMP 1.03 1.04 1.07 1.07 1.07

but now is

YEARS   2015 2016 2017 2018 2019

IMP 1.03 1.03 1.03 1.03 1.03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IMP[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1])
```

Change this to:

```
IMP[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[i+1])
```

you are only getting the second element from the IMP array which is equal to 1.03.

**EDIT**

Replace the while loop with:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < split.length){
    IMP[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[i]);
    i++;
}
double lastValue = IMP[i - 1];
while(i < years){
    IMP[i] = lastValue;
    i++;
}
```

This should do the trick if you want to repeat the last value for the remainder of the number of years. If you experience any issues, try replacing `Double.parseDouble(split[i])` with `Double.parseDouble(split[i + 1])`, or try to debug and see what values are in what variables during the execution.

Comment: When i change to split[i+1] then  output is twKI 1.03 1.05 1.07 0.0 0.0 ( should be twKI 1.03 1.04 1.07 1.07 1.07) and throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.